# Caching with Play framework and Java

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, browser-cache, expires-header

I am running an application with Play and Java, and I need to set up expiration date for various types of assets: images, css, javascript etc.

I have the following in the conf/routes file:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

I was able to set expiration date for one individual file in `application.conf`:

```
"assets.cache./public/js/pages/validation.js"="max-age=7200"
```

But I am not able to set it for a whole folder. I have tried

```
"assets.cache./public/js/pages/*.js"="max-age=7200"
"assets.cache./public/js/pages/*"="max-age=7200"
```

but nothing happens. I was hoping to set the expiration date for everything in the /js/pages folder.

I've also tried

```
assets.defaultCache="max-age=7200"
```

per instructions at
http://www.jamesward.com/2014/04/29/optimizing-static-asset-loading-with-play-framework

as well as

```
http.cacheControl=7200
```

per documentation http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/configuration#http

and none of these work. The changes above were done in application.conf.

I know there is a way to do the same by defining controllers that change the response() for the routes that I want to set the expiration date for:
[far future Expires header for static contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902855/far-future-expires-header-for-static-contents)

But I would like to know how to configure expiration date for assets from the application.conf file.

Our application is running on **S3 Linux instances,** so configuring the expire date on the server is not an option.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Play framework does not support `"assets.cache./public/js/pages/*.js"="max-age=7200"`
but `assets.defaultCache="max-age=7200"` should work.

In debug/dev mode (starting app using play run) `assets.defaultCache` is ignored, so it is always 'no-cache'. Make sure you are running it in prod mode(using play start).

I can't find any reference in docs, but same can be checked in `https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/controllers/Assets.scala` `AssetInfo::cacheControl` function

Comment: Could you please reference the specific  documentation of Play2 in your answer